# Is it safe to write Android compatible code this way?

Tags: android, dalvik

is it safe to write such compatible code on Android?

```
if (Build.os.SDK_INT >= 11) {
    newClass instance = new newClass();
    ....
}
else {
    oldClass instance = new oldClass();
    ....
}
```

one of my colleagues argue with me that ClassNotFoundException might be thrown up when running the above code since ClassLoader is attempting to load newClass on an android os device which is below android 11. But I've tried couple times, and didn't see this happen. 
After googling around for couple hours, I didn't find any information on how and when android default classLoader loads a specific class.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the compatability like the following... It gives you more accurate than the above:

```
   private static int currentApi = 0;

   public static int getApiLevel() {

    if (currentApi > 0) {
        return currentApi;
    }

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK.equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
        currentApi = 3;
    } else {
        try {
            Field f = android.os.Build.VERSION.class.getDeclaredField("SDK_INT");
            currentApi = (Integer) f.get(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return currentApi;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this cover the device below android version 4. It's safe to use SDK_INT directly when the minimal sdk version is greater than 4.

Comment: yeah you can use SDK_INT directly

Answer (score 0):

you can alway use `reflection` to check if the class exists:

```
try {
  Class.forName("yourclass")
} catch (ClassNotFoundExecption) {
  oldClass instance = new oldClass();
}
```

Comment: Sure, using reflection is doable on Android. However reflection brings  performance issue in the same time, that's why I am trying to avoid use it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is safe to do on recent versions of Android. I want to say froyo and above, but it may have been even earlier than that. I don't recall for sure.

What happens is that dalvik performs a verification pass on the dex file at install time. For any classes/methods/fields that it can't resolve, it replaces those accesses with an instruction that throws a VerifyError.

In your example, if that code got loaded on, e.g. api 10, `newClass instance = new newClass()` would conceptually be replaced with `throw new VerifYError()`. So as long as that branch never gets executed at runtime, everything is good.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer - don't do it.

Most VMs only load a class when it is absolutely needed. However a class loader is allowed to cache binary representation of classes beforehand[1].

> Class loaders are allowed to cache binary representations of types,
>   load types early in anticipation of eventual use, or load types
>   together in related groups.

[1] - http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/lifetype2.html

[2] - http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

Edit - Have you checked if the class you need is available as part of the android support package ? [2]

Comment: Using support library is the last choice in my eyes, since it will increase the apk size.

Comment: "In other words, if a class loader encounters a missing or malformed class file during early loading, it must wait to report that error until the class's first active use by the program. If the class is never actively used by the program, the class loader will never report the error."   Seems the exception is thrown only when the class is actively used by program. But this is jvm specification, I am not sure how dalvik vm on android handle this.

Comment: I stand corrected. I would still use a support package instead of writing code that conditionally loads classes. Support classes for V13 only introduce an overhead of ~400 kb